# VueJS token cleared by vue-router beforeEach

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jwt, jhipster, vuex

I have a VueJS app with Vuetify framework, which connects to a Jhipster Java backend.

I used Vuex to store the user authentication token with the help of this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-authentication-in-vue-using-vuex), storing the token on `localStorage`.

My problem is that whenever i duplicate the tab i'm working on, the `beforeEach` function is fired twice and clears the token on the second execution and directs to login page, same applies if i close the tab and tries to re open it.

Here is my code when the user logs in in `store.js`:

```
login({commit}, user){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    commit('auth_request');
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: api.AUTHENTICATE, 
        data: user, 
    })
    .then(response => {
      const token = response.data.id_token;
      localStorage.setItem('token', token)
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token;
      commit('auth_success', token);
      resolve(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      commit('auth_error')
      localStorage.removeItem('token')
      reject(error)
    })
  });
},
```

then my code in `main.js` to check is the token is present:

```
Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
if (token) {
    console.log("token exists")
  Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
}
else{
    console.log("no token");
}
```

the `beforeEach` function in `vue-router`:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  let currentUser = store.getters.isLoggedIn;
  let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  console.log("to: "+to.path+" user: "+currentUser+ " auth: "+requiresAuth);

  if (requiresAuth && currentUser){
    console.log("logged: "+store.state.token);
    next();
  }
  else if (requiresAuth && !currentUser){
    console.log("not logged: "+store.state.token);
    next('/login');
  }
  else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser){
    console.log("rediect: "+store.state.token);
        next('/dashboard');
  }
    else{
    console.log("exception")
    next();
    } 
})
```

When ever i log into the app, i get the token and redirected to dashboard page:

```
to: /dashboard user: true auth: true
logged: eyJhbGciOiJ....
```

but when i duplicate the tab or close and reopen the tab: i get this:

```
token exists
to: /dashboard user: true auth: true
logged: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxM...
to: /login user: false auth: false
exception
```

i noticed that the `beforeEach` is executed twice. If i try to refresh the first page after this, the token is cleared and i am redirected to login.

Comment: Vuex store data gets reset if you open a new tab or refresh the page, it doesn't persist, that's why you should be using the localStorage

Comment: @Luigi i am using localStorage

Comment: The problem is that every time you will refresh or open a new tab your vuex store data will get reset, the store values won't persist on page refresh forced from the user unfortunately, unless you rely on your local storage as your first source of validation.